# Why code with === does not work whereas works fine with ==?

Tags: laravel

In laravel, I was going through Intermediate tutorial of task list and encountered an issue. If you go to this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate#deleting-tasks, under heading "Authorization", you will find below mentioned code:

```php
public function destroy(User $user, Task $task)
{
    return $user->id === $task->user_id;
}
```

Here the `destroy` method works fine when it contains `return $user->id == $task->user_id;` but does not work when it contains `return $user->id === $task->user_id;`. Why?

Difference in both the code is of `==` and `===`.

Comment: === operator check both value and type. Google it: http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Thanks. You were also correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May this help you.

When comparing values in PHP for equality you can use either the `==` operator or the `===` operator.

What’s the difference between the 2? Well,

it’s quite simple.

The `==` operator just checks to see if the left and right values are equal. But,

the `===` operator (note the extra `=`) actually checks to see if the left and right values are equal, and also checks to see if they are of the same variable type (like whether they are both booleans, ints, etc.).

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thanks. I checked both the ends using var_dump() and found one of the type 'int' and another of 'string' which was restricting the === to get true.

Comment: = assignment, == two values is equal, === two values is equal and the same type.